# No new lines with custom text?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw multi-line text to Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756975/draw-multi-line-text-to-canvas)

I'm trying to draw text to a canvas using a paint, and I've uploaded my own text tff file, and it works, but when I try to do a new line, either via '\n' or The System property, its still all on the same line, but there is a box where the line should break. What gives?

Comment: It is duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6756975/525978).

Comment: Just because the same issue exists in another question doesn't make it a duplicate. That question is not in the "related" or "Similar" question lists and I couldn't find it by using the terminology I used in my question. Thus it's not a duplicate cause if you search for my question you won't find that one. Who cares anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing and not working with text.

Comment: Ah, well dang... that's annoying. You would think if it supports alignment, fonts, and shadows, it would support a line break.