# Convert text to image file on Android

Tags: java, android, file-format

I have a text document (.txt). I want to convert it to an image (.png or .jpg). For example, black text on white background. How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this (untested) code should get you on the right track.

```
void foo(final String text) throws IOException{
    final Paint textPaint = new Paint() {
        {
            setColor(Color.WHITE);
            setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
            setTextSize(20f);
            setAntiAlias(true);
        }
    };
    final Rect bounds = new Rect();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width(), bounds.height(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); //use ARGB_8888 for better quality
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, 20f, textPaint);
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(...); //create your FileOutputStream here
    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 85, stream);
    bmp.recycle();
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: problem is i could not give "\n" with in text to make it come next line

Comment: Canvas.drawText() does not handle line breaks. There is a (ugly) workaround though. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756975/draw-multi-line-text-to-canvas) for details.

Answer (score 13):

I think the proper way for multi-line text is this:

```
String text = "This \nis \nmultiline";

final Rect bounds = new Rect();
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint() {
    {
        setColor(Color.WHITE);
        setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        setTextSize(20f);
        setAntiAlias(true);
    }
};
textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint,
            bounds.width(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
int maxWidth = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < mTextLayout.getLineCount(); i++) {
    if (maxWidth < mTextLayout.getLineWidth(i)) {
        maxWidth = (int) mTextLayout.getLineWidth(i);
    }
}
final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(maxWidth , mTextLayout.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bmp.eraseColor(Color.BLACK);// just adding black background
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(...); //create your FileOutputStream here
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 85, stream);
bmp.recycle();
stream.close();
```

Comment: Question was tagged with Android so ... :)

Comment: Yes, left the comment as a warning to people like me who google brings here on a non-android search :)

Comment: The size of text is very small when a line contains many characters.

Comment: The best answer after hour of search for suitable solution! Someone recommended ```xmlgraphics-commons``` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/xmlgraphics-commons/2.9. Pure Java, but worth to explore.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/xmlgraphics-commons/1.3.1

I can provide you sample code if you want.

**Edit**: simple example:
    package v13;

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.codec.png.PNGImageEncoder;

public class Deneme {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jf.add(jp); 
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("trial text");
        jf.add(jl);
        jf.setSize(300, 200);

        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        int temp = jfc.showSaveDialog(jfc);
        if (temp == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println(jfc.getSelectedFile());
            Component myComponent = jf;
            Dimension size = myComponent.getSize();
            BufferedImage myImage = new BufferedImage(size.width,
                    size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2 = myImage.createGraphics();
            myComponent.paint(g2);
            try {
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(jfc
                        .getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()
                        + ".png");
                PNGImageEncoder encoder = new PNGImageEncoder(out, null);
                encoder.encode(myImage);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: ya i want sample can u plz provide