# Convert text to image file on Android by Right Align

Tags: android

This Example Work Correctly for conver text to image left  align (TextPaint.Align.LEFT)
but when in change it to  TextPaint.Align.RIGHT  converted image was empty.

[Convert text to image file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973048/convert-text-to-image-file-on-android)

this is my code:

```
final TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint() 
{
    {
        setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        setTextAlign(TextPaint.Align.RIGHT);
        setTextSize(textSize);
        setTypeface(NormalFont(getApplicationContext()));
        setAntiAlias(true);
    }
};
final Rect bounds = new Rect();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width(), bounds.height()+buttonPadding, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //use ARGB_8888 for better quality //RGB_565
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawText(text, 0, textSize, textPaint);
return bmp;
```

}

Comment: put your code here and give more describtions

Comment: what is purpose of convert text into image for like captcha?

Comment: @StackOverflowUser So automatic bots cannot read them, it's captcha purpose anyway? Usually after text, they will add more `noise`s.