# Create an image with white background with provided text on it

Tags: android, image, bitmap, lib

Is there any library in Android such that if it is provided with a text, it converts it into an image with a white background?

Comment: does this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973048/convert-text-to-image-file-on-android ?

Comment: What's your use case? Why do you want this?

Comment: @Charlie i want to create an application in which i have a bunch of texts. and when i press click on a particular text the application returns me the image with that text on it.

Comment: @aninditaPani . it sure does . thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/Korilakkuma/CanvasView