# How can get Gallery2's album Width and Height

Tags: android, gallery

The picture like below.

- Tap **Gallery2**, then show the album .Like the below picture

[image: images]

How can I get this album's **Width** and **Height**  (The center of this )?

- Tap **Album**,then show the details,Like the below picture

[image: images2]

Question:

How can I get those album's **Width** and **Height** (each 7 image).

Comment: How can I mark in Thumbnail?