# Newline character in a text using canvas.drawText

Tags: java, android, newline, android-canvas, drawtext

I'm doing an Android Game, and I'm using a function like this to show texts on the device screen:

```
public void drawString(String text, int x, int y, Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);

}
```

And I try to show the following message:

```
g.drawString("Player: " + playerString+ " :\n" + messageString,SCREENWIDTH / 2, SCREENHEIGHT / 2, paint);
```

However instead of a newline (\n) I get a strange character (a square).

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `drawString` call `drawText`
and for break lines call drawText twice with Y offset.

look here for example 
[Draw multi-line text to Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756975/draw-multi-line-text-to-canvas)

Answer (score 5):

```java
public void drawString(Canvas canvas, String text, int x, int y, TextPaint paint) {
   if (text.contains("\n")) {
      String[] texts = text.split("\n");
      for (String txt : texts) {
         canvas.drawText(txt, x, y, paint);
         y += paint.getTextSize();
      }
   } else {
      canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
   }
}
```