# String new line inserting not working on Canvas

Tags: android, string, canvas, insert, line

Ι want to insert new line to my String to draw my Text on Canvas , but i cant figure it out , it is being drawn all the way horizontally. I tried using an XML resource and converting from integer. Also double backslash or forthslash. Nothing. Anything wrong with the canvas? Any help appreciated

```
 private Paint myPaint;
 private String myText;
 myPaint = new Paint();
 myPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
 myPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
 myPaint.setTextSize(25);

 myText = "FIRST PART\nSECOND PART\nTHIRD PART\nFOURTH PART";
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText(myText,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/3,myPaint);
}
```

Comment: Use a StaticLayout class

Comment: some code span example?

Comment: Just call its `draw()` method in `onDraw`

Comment: u mean the one with the canvas parameter. No not working

Comment: Yes,  in onDraw(Canvas) call StaticLayout.draw(Canvas)

Comment: Non-static method draw(android.graphics.canvas) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: i think there must be something going wrong with "\n" quote. What is your opinion?

Comment: Of course its non static,  first you have tto get StaticLayout instance by calling its constructor

Comment: thanks for the help . i will check it out later and post back.

Comment: again , any code sample would be great :P

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756975/draw-multi-line-text-to-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawText will not honor \n entries.

You need to draw text 3 times and increment the height by the height of the font ( display metrics ).

Comment: thank all , drawing it 3 times is working perfeclty.

Comment: @ΙγνάτιοςΓληνός No, no, no don't do that,  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8369690/2252830

Comment: @ΙγνάτιοςΓληνός use a StaticLayout,  it not only can draw several lines of text but also it automatically breakes your text into multiple lines and finally it can draw rich text aka spans e. g.  ForegroundColorSpan,  BackgroundColorSpan etc

Comment: I don't think drawing 3 lines is a terrible solution. That said, I did not know about StaticLayout...nice.

Comment: @mjstam it is, since you have to break your text into multiple lines and most likely you will not do that in the optimal way...

Comment: Tried this (text is array and is length is 2 for two lines separated by \n): 

for (int loop = 0; loop < text.length; loop++) {
                    textCanvas.drawText(text[loop], 0, (Math.abs(fontMetrics.top) + fontMetrics.bottom) * (loop + 1), paint);
                }

Its giving two lines but with less spacing .