# How to use Glide to manage local Bitmaps?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-glide

I want to use Glide (4.8.0) to manage my Bitmap locally.
**No URLs or HTTP connections**

For saving:
I need it to save to internal storage (along with memory cache of course), So I will have to provide a specific key.

For Loading:
Get the bitmap from Glide by key.

I tried the following:

```
GlideApp.with(applicationContext)
                .load(myBitmap)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .signature(ObjectKey(generateConversationKey(name, group)))
                .submit()
```

And Tried to load:

```
        GlideApp.with(binding.root.context).load(conversation.contactKey).into(binding.profile)
```

(I Must use keys as I'm loading bitmaps in service and no there is no UI releated)
But with no luck.

Comment: I think that this answer will solve you issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893343/1481408

Comment: It seems (in glide 3 at least) that loading a bitmap directly is not supported