# Line break in AndroidPlot domain label

Tags: android, androidplot

In AndroidPlot, is it possible to break the line of a domain label? I'm plotting against time and the date representation String can be quite long and would look best if it was broken into two rows.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not currently possible.  The reason is due to Androidplot's use of Canvas.drawText(...) - see [Draw multi-line text to Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756975/draw-multi-line-text-to-canvas) for a general description of the issue.