# Textview at the center of canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview

I need to create a canvas in which i have add two images as BITMAP and a TEXTVIEW at the bottom right with multiple line.

Here is my code which i have tried -

```
drawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1500, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawnBitmap);

    canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.creamColor));
    // JUST CHANGE TO DIFFERENT Bitmaps and coordinates .

    canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b2, 630, 250, null);
    //for more images :
    // canvas.drawBitmap(b3, 0, 0, null);
    // canvas.drawBitmap(b4, 0, 0, null);

      /*Draw text*/
    //TextPaint paintText=new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paintText.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paintText.setTextSize(50);
    Typeface tf;
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf");
    paintText.setTypeface(tf);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setText(INNERTEXT);
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    textView.setWidth(300);

    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textView.setTypeface(tf);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    layout.addView(textView);


    layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    // To place the text view somewhere specific:
    // canvas.translate(500, 750);

    canvas.drawBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache(), 500, 750, null);
    // layout.draw(canvas);
```

I have divided the canvas into 4 equal parts, but the textview inside the 4. part is not centered.

Comment: Why don't you just `drawText()` on the `Canvas`, instead of trying to use a `TextView` and a `ViewGroup`'s drawing cache to do it? What you're doing is much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: drawText() is not allowing multiline.

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean by "multiple line". Use a `StaticLayout`. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8369690).

Comment: Sorry but i have to do it with i Textview

Comment: OK, but a `TextView` is itself using a `StaticLayout` to do the same thing. You're just adding unnecessary layers of complexity.

Comment: How can i align the textview at the centre of 4th part of canvas?