# Set letter spacing to drawTextOnPath

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-paint

I am using following code to make a spinner wheel.

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for (int i = 0; i < segmentColors.length; i ++)
        {
            drawDataSet(canvas, i);
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, getWidth() - getWidth()/2 - dpToPx(5), mTransparentCirclePaint);
    }


protected void drawDataSet(Canvas canvas, int position)
    {
        int color = segmentColors[position];
        float mainArcAngle = ((float) 360/ (float)segmentColors.length);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        if ( position%2 == 0)
            paint.setColor(color);
        else
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#009f2f"));

        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getWidth());
        canvas.drawArc(rect, (mainArcAngle * position), mainArcAngle, true, paint);

        TextPaint mTextPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(18f);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.addArc(rect, (mainArcAngle * position), mainArcAngle);

        //PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(path, false);
        //DynamicLayout layout = new DynamicLayout(values[position], values[position], mTextPaint, (int) pm.getLength(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 0, true);
        //canvas.save();
        //layout.draw(canvas);
        //canvas.restore();
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(values[position], path, 0 , getWidth() / 6 , mTextPaint );
    }
```

The text that is written inside the arc is a bit compressed because of small spacing. How can I make it multiline or increase letter spacing?

Comment: @IbrahimAli explain maybe?

Comment: There is no such method @IbrahimAli

Answer (score 7):

Starting from API 21 you can use [`Paint#setLetterSpacing(float)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setLetterSpacing(float)):

> Set the paint's letter-spacing for text. The default value is 0. The value is in 'EM' units. Typical values for slight expansion will be around 0.05. Negative values tighten text.

You may also [see](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3122) how `TextView#setLetterSpacing()` is implemented.

Comment: would have used it but i can not make the project go above 14 min

Comment: would be better if i can multiline the text

Comment: Have you experimented with [`StaticLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369690/1083957)?

Comment: Tried with both DynamicLayout and Static as u can see in comments, however the text isn't centred in arc anymore and is outside the bounds of Circle.