# Newline is not working in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have string label = 20. I have added label prefix as "Goal" .in between i added \n . Two lines are not coming instead one line only appearing.I need Expected Output.

Expected Output:

```
Goal                  
20
```

ActualOutput:

```
Goal20
```

I have tried below methods, its not working

```
  string label = Goal;
  string cReturns = System.Environment.NewLine + "\n" + "\r";
  string[] words = label.Split(cReturns.ToCharArray());
  label = words +20;
```

or

```
label = "Goal\n20";
```

CAN ANYONE SUGGEST ME CORRECT ANSWER

Thanks

Comment: You want add a newline to a `TextView` in `Android` ?

Comment: No. i added label as clr property with type string .

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more. I don't get what you mean.

Comment: public class MyCustomView : View{    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    { Paint p = new Paint();
            p.TextSize = 50;
            string lab = "Target\n";
            string val = lab + "20";
            canvas.DrawText(val, 100, 100, p);
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
    }
}

Comment: I have added custom view in main class.If i add a normal textview in mainclass newline is added.If i add drawtext in customview its not working

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Comment: I have calculated as if \n comes,labels are splitted and height of the labels is increased

Comment: Happy coding. : )

Answer (score 0):

You try `&#10;` instead of \n:
label = "Goal`&#10;`20";

Answer (score 0):

> If i add drawtext in customview its not working

You could  strip the `\n` and then offset the `Y` to get your text on the next line.

For Example :

```
string lab = "Goal";
canvas.DrawText(lab, 100, 100, p);
canvas.DrawText("20", 100, 150, p);
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ok9t.png).

Comment: \n wont work for drawtext? is there any other solution?

Comment: @bhuvana, this is the simplest solution, for more information, you could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756975/draw-multi-line-text-to-canvas

Answer (score 0):

using `System.Environment.NewLine` will help.

for example:

```
await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Connection Problem!", "Can't 
access backEnd at the moment Please try again later!" 
                + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.Message,
                "OK");
```