# How to calculate the height of a string with fixed width in android?

Tags: java, android

Like what method sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: does in iOS. Thanks!

I'm sorry I didn't describe my question clearly. 
I can get the width and height of a given string with the method Paint.getTextBounds(String text, int start, int end, Rect bounds), but in this way, the given string is drawn in a single line. Now I wanna fix the width of the given string, and calculate the heigth of it.

For example, the given string is "abcdefghijklmn", the textsize is 20sp and the width of the drawn text is fixed to 100dp, then the string should be drawn like below, and I want to calculate the height of it. Please ignore the redundant line break below.

abcde

fghij

klmn

Comment: [This should be what you need](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)

Comment: You have probably more chance to get an answer when you explain what this iOS function does.

Comment: Are you going to get the offer and rise in one of the activities?
Like , .getHeight();
.getWidth();

Comment: Isn't `textView.getHeight()` what you want?

Comment: I need not only calculate the height of the string but also draw it in multiple lines, StaticLayout can solve my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756975/draw-multi-line-text-to-canvas/8369690#8369690

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the height of the string without drawing it first?

Comment: You don't have to draw the `StaticLayout` for it to calculate its height.