# What is the substitute for deprecated StaticLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, staticlayout

What should be used instead of:

```
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, false);
```

Gives this warning:

> warning: [deprecation]
>   StaticLayout(CharSequence,TextPaint,int,Alignment,float,float,boolean)
>   in StaticLayout has been deprecated
>               StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, false);

Comment: I highly recommend downloading the sources of whichever Android API you are targeting, which will also include javadocs. For example, the constructor you are using has the following javadoc:

    /**
     * @deprecated Use {@link Builder} instead.
     */

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `StaticLayout.Builder`.
Go through here for more details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.Builder

for your case use:

```
StaticLayout.Builder sb = StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(text, 0, text.length(), paint, width)
                          .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                          .setLineSpacing(mSpacingAdd, mSpacingMult)
                          .setIncludePad (false);
StaticLayout layout = sb.build();
```

Comment: Unfortunate, StaticLayout.Builder requires API 23 or above. My project is compatible with API 21.

Comment: You can use this if you want:- `// Check if we're running on Android 6.0 or higher
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   StaticLayout.Builder sb= StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(text, paint, width)
                          .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
                          .setLineSpacing(mSpacingAdd, mSpacingMult)
                          .setIncludePad (false);
StaticLayout layout = sb.build();   
} else {
    StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, false);
}`